# How to enable Eventlistener to repeat animation?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have this simple annimation:

```
TranslateAnimation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 100);
transAnim.FillAfter = true;
transAnim.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
transAnim.Duration = 500;
btnAwesome.StartAnimation(transAnim);
```

And when it has finished going down, I want to repeat the animation, just have it going up again.
So basically I need to find out how to assign the listener and handle something like "onAnimationEnd". BUt I couldn't figure out how. Can you guys tell me how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        transAnim.AnimationEnd += delegate
        {
            AnimForBtnAwesome(1f);
        };
```

that was simple. thanks!